# Why automatic recompile doesn't work for C# classes in Visual Studio asp.net core mvc project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC simple project. When I start it without debugging (Ctrl + F5) and change any .cs File (Controller, for example), save it, and update the page in browser nothing happens. But it should automatically recompile and show changes, that was said in the book that I read.

Why can this happen?

I use Visual Studio 2019, .Net core 2.1.

If I manually close the page, and press start without debugging again it recompile and show changes in browser.

If I change .cshtml files (View) it takes effect as soon as I update the browser Page. So it is problem only with C# classes.

**UPD** `dotnet watch`  works just fine for that purpose, but author of the book (*A.Freeman, Pro ASP.Net core MVC 2 7th edition, chapter 6*) did not use it:

> *Visual Studio supports detecting changes as soon as an HTTP request is received from the browser and recompiling classes automatically. To
>   see how this works, select Start Without Debugging. Once the browser
>   displays the application data, make the changes to the Home
>   controller. Save the changes to the controller class file and reload
>   the browser window without stopping or restarting the application in
>   Visual Studio. The HTTP request from the browser will trigger the
>   compilation process, and the application will be restarted using the
>   modified controller class*

Why does this not work for me?

Comment: Did you try using `dotnet watch` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book was written for Visual Studio 2017. It works as the book describes in VS 2017.

However, according to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8140#issuecomment-469206749), the auto-rebuild feature has not yet been added to Visual Studio 2019.

---

*Original answer: (which applies when that feature is not available):*
The difference is that .cs files are compiled into your project's DLL at compile time. For any new code to take effect, the DLL needs to be updated, which will only happen if you specifically tell it to recompile. This is why, when you deploy your project, you copy over the .dll file and *not* the .cs files.

However, views (.cshtml files) stay as plain text files and are compiled when you use them. If you edit a .cshtml, it's recompiled the next time the view is used. This is why, when you deploy your project, you *do* need to copy the .cshtml files.

Visual Studio does have a feature to let you modify .cs files while debugging and have it take effect immediately, but it doesn't support ASP.NET projects. It's called [Edit and Continue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue-visual-csharp?view=vs-2019).

However, you can setup `dotnet watch` to detect file changes and restart your application. There are instructions on how to do that here: [Develop ASP.NET Core apps using a file watcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: The problem is, that I read the book about ASP.Net core MVC (by Adam Freeman, 7th edition) and it says that I can modify .cs files while application is working (but it should be started without debugging). Nothing about dotnet watch, only start my application with ctrl+f5. "Visual Studio supports detecting changes as soon as an HTTP request is received from the browser and recompiling classes automatically". But this is (for some reason) doesn't work for me. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Without seeing the book and how he instructs you to setup the project, no, I can't say. But, as you have seen, if you just create a new project and do nothing else, it won't recompile automatically.

Comment: "Visual Studio supports detecting changes as soon as an HTTP request is received from the browser and recompiling classes automatically. To see how this works, select Start Without Debugging. Once the browser displays the application data, make the changes to the Home controller.  Save the changes to the controller class file and reload the browser window without stopping or restarting the application in Visual Studio. The HTTP request from the browser will trigger the compilation process, and the application will be restarted using the modified controller class". Not a word about any command

Comment: I don't know what he's talking about then. I just tried it and it does not behave that way for me.

Comment: However, dotnet watch works just fine for that purpose. 
But I'm anyway interested why it is not working the way it was described in a book. I suppose this is the most popular book about Asp.net core MVC. And I can't found a single person with this problem on the internet, so I just decided to ask myself. This is pretty strange (any other problems in this book I can find how to solve without asking myself). Maybe you can help me with where I should look for answer?

Comment: I found the [sample projects](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-mvc-2) for the book and tried it myself. It does actually work as described in VS 2017, but not in VS 2019 (I have both versions installed). Turns out the feature just hasn't been added to 2019 yet. I've updated my answer.